# PL SQL Using User Defined Type

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

This is my defined type :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE new_type AS OBJECT(pname VARCHAR2(10), quan NUMBER(4));
```

This is the function i want to use  :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_max(mon IN  VARCHAR2)

RETURN new_type

AS

    type_var new_type;

    CURSOR c1 IS SELECT pr.pname,o.quan FROM product pr, orders o WHERE pr.pid=o.pid AND o.quan=(SELECT MAX(quan) FROM orders WHERE TO_CHAR(o_date,'MM')=mon) AND TO_CHAR(o_date,'MM')=mon;

BEGIN

    OPEN c1;

    FETCH c1 INTO type_var.pname,type_var.quan;

    RETURN type_var;

END get_max;
```

The execution block :

```
DECLARE
    type_var new_type;
BEGIN
    type_var:=get_max('03');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(type_var.pname||' '||type_var.quan); 
END;
```

I am trying to get the product name and its order quantity for a particular month which has the maximum order quantity for that given month
[This is the order table i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKpNk.png),

the result should be

```
facewash    10
```

for the month of march

And on running the execution block the error i get is :

Error report -

> ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.GET_MAX", line 8
>
> ORA-06512: at line 4
>
> 6530. 00000 -  "Reference to uninitialized composite"

*`Cause`:    An object, LOB, or other composite was referenced as a
           left hand side without having been initialized.

*`Action`:   Initialize the composite with an appropriate constructor
           or whole-object assignment.

Comment: btw it's good practice or at least a good habit to close the cursor, even though in this case it should get closed automatically when the function returns.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you never run a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ7096), hence the (correct) error message:

```
 * Cause: An object, LOB, or other composite was referenced as a left hand
   side without having been initialized.
 * Action: Initialize the composite with an appropriate constructor or
   whole-object assignment.
```

Change your cursor to run the construct `new_type()`:

```
CURSOR c1 IS SELECT new_type(pr.pname, o.quan) FROM ...
```

And then in the `fetch` simply assign to the variable:

```
FETCH c1 INTO type_var;
```

And as usual all this and more is available for free in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/toc.htm).

Answer (score 0):

When you use a record type variable inside your block, prior to assigning value to the variable, you need to INITIALIZE the variable. As you have not done that here, it is correctly throwing the error as Reference to UNINITIALIZED composite.

To initialize it, inside BEGIN, you need to do the following prior to fetching value into it -

```
BEGIN

  type_var := new_type('',0);

  OPEN c1;
  FETCH c1 
  INTO type_var.pname,type_var.quan;
  RETURN type_var;
  CLOSE c1;

END;
```

The rest of the body would remain the same as your code.

One more thing...you need to close the cursor after fetch is done. Its not there, please fix it.